# How to set DateField value using a string containing the date and time?

Tags: blackberry, date, datefield, rim-4.5, blackberry-os-v4.5

I have the following string "29/05/2012 12:11 PM"
i want to add this value to a DateField

i did it like this:

```
String dateTime = "29/05/2012 12:11 PM";
long initialDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat SDF_DateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa");
DateField DF_DateTime = new DateField("Time: ", initialDateTime , SDF_DateTime, Field.FIELD_LEFT | DrawStyle.LEFT | Field.FOCUSABLE);
DF_DateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
DF_DateTime.setDate(stringToDate(dateTime));
add(DF_DateTime);
```

where

```
public Date stringToDate(String s) 
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)));
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3, 5)) - 1);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6, 10)));
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(11, 13)));
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(14, 16)));
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, s.substring(17, 19).toLowerCase().equals("am") ? Calendar.AM : Calendar.PM);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

But the field shows: "**30**/05/2012 12:11 **AM**"
instead of "**29**/05/2012 12:11 **PM**"

If it's usefull to know, my device is set in options to the following timezone: "Dublin, London (GMT)"

Is there any logical interpretation of what is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, here it is for those who are interested:

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(11, 13)) % 12);
```

Because in the javadoc for `Calendar.HOUR` it's specified that:

> HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0
>   - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12